# Remove the spaces between Gridview in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to remove the spaces between gridview children. I will provide an image of what I need and what below respectively.
I used the GridView() by the way.

```
 GridView(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3, ),
            children: <Widget>[
                ...sections
            ],
          ),
```

sections is a list of widgets.

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t376s.jpg)

[What I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOonN.png)

apologise, I am unable to show images my questions yet.

Comment: Try this way **GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            children: List.generate(100, (index) {
              return
                Container(
                  color: index%2==0?Colors.green:Colors.orange,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Item $index',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                ;
            }),
          ),
        ));**

Comment: may be the child widgets has margins set!!

Answer (score 11):

I used `GridView.count` a lot within my apps. You can just remove the bottom padding of a GridView using `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`.

Answer (score 4):

```
gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    childAspectRatio: 4.0,
  ),
```

Try with altering the values. I think this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

Your children probably have margin.

See this.

```
       GridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 3,
            mainAxisSpacing: 1,
            crossAxisSpacing: 1,
          ),
          children: List.generate(
            20,
            (index) => Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(Icons.touch_app, size: 30, color: Colors.yellow[900],),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Text("Touch", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Gracias, it actually did. I had padding on the widget that was generated.